# Can not access Glue table from Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

[image]

No tables are found when creating data source.
If Custom sql is selected I get error -
Insufficient permissions to execute the query. Insufficient Lake Formation permission.

My quicksight service role has all permissions.
My user console role has all permissions.
I Granted Lake formation permissions to my user and quicksight service role.
Nothing helped.
And yes the table and quicksight are in same region.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? having same issue

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickSight service role (something like "aws-quicksight-service-role-v0") needs LakeFormation permissions in order to add datasets to QuickSight. Go to the LakeFormation console and grant Select permissions on all tables you want to access in QuickSight for the quicksight service role. This is somewhat counter to what [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/lake-formation.html) suggests. In fact, I removed all Lake Formation permissions on my QuickSight user and I was still able to add the datasets given the Select permission granted to the service role. This may have something to do with QuickSight being configured to use IAM credentials when you created your QuickSight account.

Answer (score -1):

In Lake Formation, you can grant fine-grained control to a principal (IAM, **QuickSight**, or Active Directory) to any Data Catalog resource.

If you are logged in to the AWS Console as the data lake administrator:

1. Go to: Lake Formation -> Permissions -> Data Lake permissions
2. Select "Grant"
3. Under "Users and Groups" choose "SAML users and groups" (**not IAM**)
4. Enter the ARN for your Quicksight user or group
5. Grant permissions to your database / table / LF Tags.

More information can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/enable-fine-grained-permissions-for-amazon-quicksight-authors-in-aws-lake-formation/).

Answer (score -2):

AWS services -> Lake Formation -> View Permissions -> Grant -> IAMAllowedPrinciples -> Grant

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you use IAMAllowedPrinciples permissions, you lose the ability to create fine-grained access control to your data. This option is the default to allow backwards compatibility to existing Glue jobs, but it would be better to upgrade to use [the Lake Formation permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/upgrade-glue-lake-formation.html).